# How to apply Stripe coupon discount only for first subscription invoice

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, payment-processing

Currently I am using Stripe in my project and I wanted to know if it is possible to apply a coupon code when I create a subscription, but applied only for that first invoice of the subscription and not for upcoming charges. Upcoming charges should be the exact amount without the coupon code applied automatically by Stripe. How can this be done via Stripe API?

I would really appreciate your hep. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Coupon you plan to use for discounting the Subscription, you should use the `duration: 'once'` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create#create_coupon-duration) to ensure the resulting discount is only applied to the initial invoice. Stripe documentation details this behaviour [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/coupons#coupon-duration).

Comment: thnak you Jonathan